# "Кажан" чи "летюча миша"? Як правильно?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, значення-слів

В усній мові людина частіше вживає словосполучення *"летюча миша"*, на мою думку, лише науковець (біолог) скаже *"кажан"*. Чи можемо вживати два варіанти, як рівні один одному?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заглянувши на сайти [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8) та [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/kazhan) можемо побачити визначення лише одного слова ***"Кажан"***

> Нічний ссавець із широкими крилами, утвореними перетинками між довгими
>   пальцями ніг.

Проте у [СУМ на слово "Миша"](http://sum.in.ua/s/mysha) є словосполучення ***"летюча миша"*** :

> ***Летюча миша***: а) те саме, що *кажан*. *Чому так добре почувають себе в
>   повітрі сліпі летючі миші? Виявилось, мають власні ультразвукові
>   «локатори»* (Знання та праця, 3, 1966, 6);  * **У порівняннях.** *Монашки
>   чорною зграєю вкрили подвір'я, мов летючі миші, обліпили ганочок* (Іван
>   Микитенко, II, 1957, 270);
>
> б) переносний гасовий ліхтар. *В корівнику було напівтемно. Ліхтар
>   «летюча миша» висів на стовпі посеред приміщення і тихо погойдувався*
>   (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 110).

Отже, слово *кажан* не завжди можемо замінити на словосполучення *летюча миша*.
В наукових працях краще використовувати слово *кажан*, у художній літературі також частіше зустрічається саме *кажан*, а ось у розмові можна послуговуватися, в принципі, і другим варіантом, хоча, звісно, в українській не заохочується зловживання дієприкметниками.

Comment: СУМ ненадїьне јерело, основна причина: совʼєтизацїя. Для [порівняння](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=Летучая+мышь&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) — жоден слоўник (окрім [Кримського (1924–33)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=мышь&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)): Ізӱмоў (1930), Вирган (1959), Нікоўськиь (1927), Грінченко (1909) — не вклӱчає слова „летӱча миша“. Також українська [не дуже схвалӱє](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дієприкметник#Вживання_дієприкметників_в_українській_мові) [зло]вживу дїєприкметникіў.